# Angularjs how to load div content only after init method called

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

i am new to AngularJs, Initially when page loads ie. when loadResponseData() is processing i need to show progress div and after ajax call completed need to show success div with response data. but success is not showing 
 after loadResponseData() is completed. Is there any way to show progress bar before completing ajax call and should show success div after response received from ajax call. Sorry for my english and kindly save my day.

```
<%
PayBean payBean = (PayBean) session.getAttribute("payData");
%>

<div ng-controller="payCtrl" ng-init="loadResponseData()" id="loadResponseData">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
        <form id="response">
            <div class="row row-space" ng-if="status=='success'">
                // load response data in elements
            </div>
            <div class="row row-space" ng-if="status=='progress'">
                // Progress bar takes place
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<div>
```

Method in payCtrl:

```
$scope.loadResponseData = function() {
    $http.post(contextRoot + getResponseData(function(data) {
        var status = sessionStorage.getItem("status");
        $scope.status  = status ;
        sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
    });
};
```

Comment: what is the `status` ? where did you declare it ?

Comment: Its declared in loadResponseData method in angularjs controller

Comment: Because you are using `ng-if` directive it create new scope so `status` isn't visible. try use controllerAs syntax or use `ng-hide` or `ng-show` directive.

Comment: Hadi.. i can get status initially as progress.. but after ajax method  loadResponseData completed the page is not refreshing

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `ng-if` directive it creates new scope so status isn't visible. try use `controllerAs` syntax or use `ng-hide` or `ng-show` directive.

Try this one

```
<div ng-controller="payCtrl as vm" ng-init="vm.loadResponseData()" id="loadResponseData">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
    <form id="response">
        <div class="row row-space" ng-if="vm.status=='success'">
            // load response data in elements
        </div>
        <div class="row row-space" ng-if="vm.status=='progress'">
            // Progress bar takes place
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>
 <div>
```

and in controller use `var vm = this;` instead `$scope`;

```
 var vm = this;
 vm.loadResponseData = function() {
 vm.post(contextRoot + getResponseData(function(data) {
    var status = sessionStorage.getItem("status");
    vm.status  = status ;
    sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
 });
};
```

Comment: Hadi, do able to get updated payBean  after loadResponseData called

Comment: Can we use new view jsp for loading and redirect to usccess page afte rloadResponseData loaded

Answer (score 1):

try this example in here `$timeout` directive replace with `$http` and use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('payCtrl',function($timeout,$scope){
    $scope.status = "progress"; //by default set as progress
    
    $scope.loadResponseData = function() {
        console.log("yes called");
        $timeout(function(){
             $scope.status = "success";
        },2000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' class="container" ng-controller="payCtrl" ng-init="loadResponseData()" id="oadResponseData">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8 center">
      <form id="response" class="success">
        <div class="row row-space" ng-show="status== 'success'">
          <h1>success code loaded</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-space" ng-show="status== 'progress'">
          <h1>Progress code loaded</h1>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: Jignesh, do able to get updated payBean after loadResponseData called